# throw new TypeError('Router.use()requires a middleware function but got a ' + gettype(fn))v

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, routes, backend

Im getting the error:

throw new TypeError('Router.use()requires a middleware function but got a ' + gettype(fn))v

I'm fairly new and not sure what is going on! Any help would be greatly appreciated and let me know if there is any other information that might be helpful. Thanks so much ahead of time!!!!!!!

Here is my app.js:

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express(); // object with methods; One method is router; express creates a server; app allows us to access the server; app.listen hooks up our server;
const morgan = require('morgan'); //app.use(...) morgan says console.log(wht app.use does);
const { db, Review, Toilet, User } = require('./server/db/index');

// Logger:
app.use(morgan('dev')); // implies '/' ('/', morgan('dev'));

//Body parser:
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(express.json());

// public:
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

// Backend Routing:
app.use('/api', require('./server/api/index'));

// Setting up server
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8880;

const syncDb = () => db.sync();

const startListening = () => {
  app.listen(PORT, function() {
    console.log(
      ` ***** I'm leisurely listening on pleasant port of ${PORT} *****`
    );
  });
};

async function bootApp() {
  await syncDb();
  await startListening();
}

bootApp();
```

Here is my sever/api/index.js:

```js
const router = require('express').Router();

router.use('/toilets', require('./toiletRoutes'));
router.use('/users', require('./userRoutes'));
router.use('/reviews', require('./reviewRoutes'));

module.exports = router;
```

Here is my sever/db/api/toiletRoutes.js:

```js
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const { Toilet, User, Review } = require('../db/index');

// Get all toilets
router.get('/', async function(req, res, next) {
  console.log('in get all toilets');
  try {
    const allToilet = await Toilet.findAll();
    res.status(200).send(allToilet);
  } catch (error) {
    next(error);
  }
});

module.exports = router;
```

Here is my package.json:

```js
{
  "name": "newflush",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "engines": {
    "npm": "6.4.1",
    "node": "10.7.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack -w & node app.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "babel": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.5",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-upgrade": "0.0.23",
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "google-map-react": "^1.1.2",
    "morgan": "^1.9.1",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "pg": "^7.8.1",
    "pg-hstore": "^2.3.2",
    "react": "^16.5.2",
    "react-burger-menu": "^2.5.4",
    "react-dom": "^16.5.2",
    "react-geocode": "^0.1.2",
    "react-google-maps": "^9.4.5",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
    "react-router": "^4.3.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "sequelize": "^4.43.0",
    "webpack": "^4.20.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.2"
  }
}
```

[Here is my server file tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mwrD9.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `index.js` is located at `sever/db/api/index.js`

and in your `app.js` you are requiring `server/api/index.js`

change it to the correct path.

**UPDATE:**

Oh I just noticed this part

```
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(express.json());
```

it should be

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

you will need to add `body-parser` module to dependencies and require it.

Comment: I labeled my file incorrectly - sorry for the confusion! my api folder isn't in my db folder - they are on the same level. I added a photo of my server file tree to my question

Comment: I've updated the answer. I hope that will solve your problem.

Answer (score 6):

*Checkout Your all Exports*
It should be:

```
module.exports = router;
```

Comment: or check your import too maybe you imported a different file with the same name!